# How to put icon center of another icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, icons, material-design

How to Put one icon in center of another icon like google map marker like below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Stack" control in which you have to add the first icon with "Pin"  and same add another with "Carry"

```
    Widget getStack() {
  return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Icon(Icons.account_balance),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Icon(Icons.account_balance),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```